# Rails syntax error ERB: expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following code is a rendering the error: 
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

```
<div id="Carousel">
    <% results = @client.search("Twitter", :result_type => "mixed").take(3).to_a %>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <p><%= "results[0].text"%></p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">                
            <p><%= "results[1].text"%></p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p><%= "results[2].text"%></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I honestly have no idea why this is happening. I've tried troubleshooting but I've gotten nowhere. I'm sure it's a little mistake but I can't figure it out. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Simply remove the `<% end %>` line. It's not needed.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. If you don't mind, can you explain why it is not needed? I though that anywhere that I included ERB I had to put a <% end %>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **iltempo** mentioned this in comment: `remove the <% end %> line.`

> If you don't mind, can you explain why it is not needed?

Because what you do at line 2 is not a block, you just set a variable there that you use later. Example of block:

```
<% User.all.each do |u| %>
 <%= u.email %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to user do %>
 <%= u.email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

the stuff between <%   %>  is ruby code.

`<%=  %>`  inserts the result into the html, so for example

`<% x = 3 %>`   will set the ruby variable x to 3 but
`<%= x = 3 %>` will set the ruby variable x to 3 and also insert the value 3 into the html

If you look at what you have in terms of ruby code it is something like this:

```
results = @client.search("Twitter", :result_type => "mixed").take(3).to_a
"results[0].text"
"results[1].text"
"results[2].text"
end
```

If you look at that, you will notice the "end" statement is out of place.
I also think you probably don't want the "" around the results statements